# Lock bitbucket repository branch after Crucible review of that branch is closed

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-crucible

Is there some Atlassian Bitbucket Crucible integration that allows a git repository feature branch to be locked after a Crucible review has been "closed". We are trying to prevent additional commits to the branch after the review is closed. This has been an issue in the past with some developers who want to sneak changes in and not go through the proper process. Once the peer review in Crucible is complete, the review creator closes the review and then uses Jira to create a pull request. We want to prevent the sneaking of code but also eliminate the need to relook at the code diff again with the pull request to make sure its accurate before merging.

Any solutions or suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Are you asking about Bitbucket Cloud (bitbucket.org) or Bitbucket Server (the self-hosted one)?

Comment: Bitbucket Server, self-hosted